# Why is runtime.Gosched not working sometimes?

Tags: go, concurrency, goroutine

My client is fairly simple. There are two goroutines as well:

1. The main goroutine: Call runtime.Gosched, then print "1".
2. The second goroutine: Print "2".

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
)

func main() {
    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(1)
    go func() {
        fmt.Println(2)
    }()

    runtime.Gosched()
    fmt.Println(1)
}
```

At the beginning, I call method runtime.GOMAXPROCS to set P count to 1, so all goroutines will run on the same thread.

When I call runtime.Gosched, The second goroutine will get chance to run, so print 2 first, then print 1.

But sometimes, Only 1 is printed, I want to know why?

My Golang version is go1.14.1

Comment: "When I call runtime.Gosched, The second goroutine will get chance to run" Correct. Note that "chance to run" != "does run".

Answer (score 2):

[`runtime.Gosched()`](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#Gosched) does not "de-prioritize" the goroutine that calls it, it just yields the processor to other goroutines. The caller goroutine remains active and may be scheduled to run again.

So in short, `runtime.Gosched()` does not guarantee how long the scheduled goroutine can run. The `main` goroutine may be re-scheduled before the other goroutine can "fully" execute the print operation. And if that happens and the `main` goroutine ends, your app ends as well (in which case you won't see `2` printed, just `1` from the `main`).

`runtime.Gosched()` cannot be used to control the goroutine scheduling, it may only be used so that a goroutine doesn't monopolize the thread it runs on.

`runtime.Gosched()` is not a synchronization tool. If you have to wait other launched goroutines, use [`sync.WaitGroup`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup) for example:

```
var wg sync.WaitGroup
wg.Add(1)
go func() {
    defer wg.Done()
    fmt.Println(2)
}()

fmt.Println(1)
wg.Wait()
```

If the launched goroutine must run first (before `main`), then there's no point running it as a separate goroutine, do the job on the `main`:

```
fmt.Println(2)

fmt.Println(1)
```